# Extracting a specific word from a URL string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a URL with a query string which starts and ends with a specific letters. Here's an example and my approach:

Let's say the url in the address bar is `"http://localhost:3001/build/?videoUrl=bitcoin.vid.com/money#/"`

I first extract this url using the `window.location.href` and save it in a variable `x`.

Now, I want to first check if the `videoUrl` is present in the URL or not and then if it is available, I split the URL and extract the required URL which is `bitcoin.vid.com/money`

```
let x = "http://localhost:3001/build/?videoUrl=bitcoin.vid.com/money#/";
let y;
let result;
if(x.indexOf("?videoUrl")>-1) {
   y = x.split("?videoUrl=");
   result = y[1].split("#")[0];
   console.log("Resultant URL:", result);
}
```

I feel the whole code which I wrote is a bit cumbersome. Could anyone let me know if there is more elegant way to do the same?

Note: `videoUrl` is not available always in the URL, hence the check if it exists. And please also let me know if I need to further make any checks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams
- https://caniuse.com/#search=URLSearchParams

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your method works, which is the main thing- but for cleaner and more robust approach, you can make use of the built-in JavaScript [`URL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) class.

```js
let x = "http://localhost:3001/build/?videoUrl=bitcoin.vid.com/money#/";
console.log((new URL(x)).searchParams.get("videoUrl"));
```

If your `videoUrl` parameter is not present, then this will just return `null`, and you can deal with that accordingly

---

If you want to make this slightly more reusable, here's a function that does what you need:

```
const getParamFromUrl = (url, param) =>
    (new URL(url)).searchParams.get(param);
```

There's plenty more information about implementation and compatibility of this in the documentation, here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

Answer (score 2):

**Good question!**

Two options for a neat solution:

- Try using the URL approach thatr @Lissy suggested, the functionality to do what you need is all built in. However she didn't mention the potential flaws when it comes to corss-browser functionality
- Alternativley, I'd just use a simple regex, e.g. `(\?|\&)([^=]+)\=([^&]+)`
   - in my opinion, it is much simpler